# Why my filter arrayhelper not showing value from database yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, frameworks

in view/index file where showing all data of model i used

```
'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Mobile::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'mobile'),
```

it works truely but not display values . and it has just some empty fields .

here is my view/index code:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper ;
use app\models\Mobile;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\MobileSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Mobiles';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="mobile-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Mobile', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
                [


                'attribute'=>'id',
                'value'=>'id',
               //'filter'=>array("1"=>"open","2"=>"in progress","3"=>"closed")
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Mobile::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'mobile'),
            ],
            'sim_num',
            'network',
            'twog_network',
            'threeg_network',
            // 'fourg_network',
            // 'technology',
            // 'gps',
            // 'gateway_connection',
            // 'super_id',
            // 'camera',
            // 'resolusion_camera',
            // 'automatic_focus',
            // 'camera_flash',
            // 'video:ntext',
            // 'camera_others:ntext',
            // 'camera_selfie:ntext',
            // 'username',
            // 'body:ntext',
            // 'title:ntext',
            // 'state',
            // 'imageFile',
            // 'size',
            // 'weight',
            // 'inner_memory',
            // 'screen_size',
            // 'screen_type',
            // 'wifi_desc',
            // 'bluetooth',
            // 'batery',
            // 'bady_struct',
            // 'process',
            // 'other:ntext',
            // 'os',
            // 'gesture',
            // 'items',
            // 'speaker',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

where

```html
<?php

   'attribute'=>'id',
                'value'=>'id',
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Mobile::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'mobile'),
            ],

?>
```

i repeat it shows number of fields and search correct when click on each fields and a little problem that it does not display values ...

in inspect element of site we have:

```
<option value="2"></option>
```

and i wanna shows '2' between option tags..

Please help me.

Comment: is option, the filter,  should show the value for mobile  and not the value for id  .. 2 is the value of id or the value of mobile??

Comment: 2 is value of id

Comment: It is not really clear to me, but if you want to put id value in the option maybe it is enough to map this way: ArrayHelper::map(Mobile::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'id');

Comment: thaaaank youu..resolved :)))

thanks a lot again :))))))))))))
;)

Comment: @areff Should I post the comment into an answer so you can close the question?

Answer (score 0):

As from the comments, here's the solution to your problem:

```
ArrayHelper::map(Mobile::find()->asArray()->all(),'id', 'id');
```